# Add ellipsis to unsalvageable triage review option

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage

*Looks OK*, *Should Be Improved*, and *Skip* are immediate actions which finish review, but *Unsalvageable* brings up a dialog box for more specifics. Could an ellipsis (`...`) be added to the button to signify that fact? Like this:

[image]

Without it, all four options seem like you'll finish the review upon clicking the button. This can lead to further confusion about what is truly "unsalvageable." For instance, maybe a question needs to be improved, but only by the OP (adding specifics we don't know). So OP could salvage it, but you still need to click *Unsalvageable* in order to close it in its currently unanswerable state.

Without knowing the dialog exists, and without feeling free to click the button to view the options, many users may make the wrong selection.

Comment: I would prefer something like  `(More...)` or at least a `[...]`. Just ending with an ellipsis makes it sound like you're unsure or trying to be mysterious.

Comment: I dunno, `File > Open...` would be a well-understood precedent

Comment: At UX.SE: [What are the rules of using ellipsis on buttons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30420/what-are-the-rules-of-using-ellipsis-on-buttons)

Comment: Instead of adding ellipses to it, how about rename it to be `Flag` because that is actually what it is doing.

Comment: @drneel once you have 3000 reputation you can cast close votes, which are different from flags but are available in the dialog